# sort multidimensional array by integer value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
[Address Line 1] => Array
    (
        [llx] => 18.96
        [lly] => 28.88999999999999
    )

[Address Line 2] => Array
    (
        [llx] => 18.73
        [lly] => 35.66
    )

[City State ZIP Code] => Array
    (
        [llx] => 18.51
        [lly] => 47.16999999999999
    )

[Full Name] => Array
    (
        [llx] => 18.86
        [lly] => 20.15999999999997
    )

 )
```

and i would like to loop through it and sort it by the lly value: so the final outcome should really be

```
Array
 (
[Full Name] => Array
    (
        [llx] => 18.86
        [lly] => 20.15999999999997
    )

[Address Line 1] => Array
    (
        [llx] => 18.96
        [lly] => 28.88999999999999
    )

[Address Line 2] => Array
    (
        [llx] => 18.73
        [lly] => 35.66
    )

[City State ZIP Code] => Array
    (
        [llx] => 18.51
        [lly] => 47.16999999999999
    )

  )
```

Any ideas on accomplishing this? Iv been looking over the sorting functions in php but they seem to be mainly focused on single dimension array and nothing like this unless im missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rudie already has the best answer for your particular case, but here's an alternative using `array_multisort`

```
$llx = array();
$lly = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
    $llx[$key] = $row['llx'];
    $lly[$key] = $row['lly'];
};
array_multisort($lly, SORT_ASC, $llx, $array);
```

Answer (score 2):

You want `uksort`. It's awesome.

```php
uksort($array, function($a, $b) {
  return $a['lly'] - $b['lly']; // might be reverse, I always forget
});
```

- `usort` is the 'normal' user sort
- `uksort` does the same, but maintains keys. With an assoc array, that seems useful.

Just for future reference, there's a lot of very useful sorters in PHP, like `natcasesort()`, which sorts 'naturally' and case insensitive. Those won't work in a multidimensional array, like you mentioned. PHP of course has the same power in a useful package: `strnatcasecmp`, so you can make a `u(k)sort` callback that leverages the `natcasesort` power.

The same power for other compare functions: `strncmp` etc

Just saying.